# jspm Chartist doesn't Import CSS Files

Tags: css, npm, aurelia, jspm, chartist.js

I'm having trouble importing chartist library with jspm Aurelia application.
Added all the styles, but still weird chart, not the colors and lines I was looking for.

Code included into the attached() method in app.ts from chartistjs homepage:

```
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';

export class App {
constructor() {}
attached() {
// Our labels and three data series
var data = {
    labels: ['Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4', 'Week5', 'Week6'],
    series: [
        [5, 4, 3, 7, 5, 10],
        [3, 2, 9, 5, 4, 6],
        [2, 1, -3, -4, -2, 0]
    ]
};

// We are setting a few options for our chart and override the defaults
var options = {

    // Don't draw the line chart points
    showPoint: false,

    // Disable line smoothing
    lineSmooth: false,

    // X-Axis specific configuration
    axisX: {

        // We can disable the grid for this axis
        showGrid: false,

        // and also don't show the label
        showLabel: false
    },

    // Y-Axis specific configuration
    axisY: {

        // Lets offset the chart a bit from the labels
        offset: 60,

        // The label interpolation function enables you to modify the values
        // used for the labels on each axis. Here we are converting the
        // values into million pound.
        labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
            return '$' + value + 'm';
        }
    }
};

// All you need to do is pass your configuration as third parameter to the   chart function
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
}
```

My app.html:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="chartist-chart" class="ct-chart"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

My Index.cshtml file:

```
<div aurelia-app="main">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
       href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
</div>
```

My chart is like:
[image: weird image]

But should be like:
[image]

reference: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html

Comment: Take a look at browser's developer tools. Is there any 404 or JavaScript error?

Comment: Can we please see how you are using the plugin? We need the contents of your ViewModel, how you are calling the plugin and how you are importing your styles, etc.

Comment: @FabioLuz no errors. But I got it working , by creating new .css file and pasting all the data there. And then using require() to import the .css file.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED] So all I needed to do is create my own '../lib/chartist.min.css' file and added the content there and needed to require it in .html template

```
<template>
    <require from="../../css/lib/chartist.min.css"></require>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Chartist</h2>
        <div id="chartist-chart" class="ct-chart"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```